# SharePoint Calendar Overlay Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, calendar

I have 10 calendar overlays (List views) on a Master calendar. Is it possible to set permissions on the calendar overlays (List views) so I can control who can view and read the items from the master calendar?

Answer (score 1):

I believe its not possible in sharepoint ootb calendar, if you wan't to audience a calendar overlay, try to have separate calendar list in every calendar overlay, that way you can give permissions to each calendar list and then the master list will just show the user what calendar he has permissions to at least view.

let me know if the concept somehow helps.

Happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint lists and items are security trimmed. To control who can view and read the items from the master calendar, you can set unique permission for the calendars/items, just grant a specific group of users' permissions on those calendars/items.

If you don't want to show those items to some people, just remove those users' permissions on those calendars/items.